# MYSQL Error1005(HY000): Can't create table (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I was doing my mysql assignment in XAMPP,but kept getting

> Error1005(HY000): Can't create table (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") 
>   And when I changed 'Course' to 'Courses' , It worked!
>   Got the same error with 'Instructor', And it worked when I changed the tablename from 'Instructor' to 'Faculty'.
>   See Images below for clarification.
>   I really want to know what's happening under the hood! 
>   [image: 1][image: 2]

Comment: You just have to read the error messages. They tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not getting this error message. I have only 1 table 'Department' in my database, So how could there be a duplicate key of 'Course' table! I don't have that table in my database.

Comment: Is there data in any table?

Comment: No. I just did Create database university,

Comment: Create table Department;

Comment: I just typed your first four commands into MySQL and got no errors. It must be a Maria thing, or a version thing.

Comment: Check that may be you have two constraint with same name. rename one

Comment: Please do not post execution of statements as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I think, mostly, you missed the constraint name like this `CONSTRAINT fk_book_author`.

You also missed `TABLE` keyword in the first screen, last query.